# Converting PPTX to PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, powerpoint

I am developing an API, in PHP, hosted on a linux server, that requires me to make jpeg previews for a .pptx powerpoint presentation.

I first convert the file to pdf and then convert the pdf to jpegs.
The second step is easy, with ghostscript, it's the first part that's proving difficult.

- I have tried using the libreoffice executable, but pptx isn't completely compatible. Certain backgrounds become invisible.
- I have the same problem with many 3rd party APIs (which I suspect also use libreoffice); the ones that do work, are ridiculously expensive.
- Installing office on a Linux server and using COM functions seems impossible, or very tedious at best.
- I have looked at Aspose.Slides, which also seems rather expensive, and their documentation is filled with errors.

I could use suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: WPS Office does a good job of handling the MS Office docs, but I cannot find any information on an API that is available for it, other than their own changelog saying it improved. https://www.wps.com/office-free

Comment: I did convert the PPTX files with Aspose.Slides but it was with PHP and C#. I don't know if the C# and Java versions of Aspose libraries are the same, but there were no errors in the C#/.NET version even with very complex PPTXs. Perhaps you can use the C# version with Mono. Or you can try the PhpPresentation library: https://phppresentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. Then you can convert the pptx to odp, which could be better edible for the open office converter.

Comment: @Lukas Converting to odp will result in the same problem. it's the format that deletes certain backgrounds.

Comment: @MrEvers - I didn't find any free solution to maintain the newest PPTX files. You said, Open/Libre/StarOffice don't do their job as expected. So, you have to try once more with the Aspose. As I said before, I used their product before and I didn't notice a problem - and I created a document to image console app, that converted every office document format  (and Sharepoint pages) to images. The clue is to find the older documentation or the forum topics about the functionality. There were inconsistencies llike Aspose.OutputFormat in the docs and Aspose.OutputFromat in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to find the underlying problem of why LibreOffice and online conversion tools have a problem with the backgrounds of the presentations I need to convert.
The background is a .emf file, which has bad support.

### **My solution**

I've unzipped the presentation, converted the .emf files to png (using ghostscript), changed all mentions of .emf to .png in the XML, and rezipped the altered presentation.

When I now use the LibreOffice headless to convert to pdf, the background shows up.

It might be a bit *hacky*, but it works for the intent of my program.

---

ps. I see that my question has gathered a few downvotes. In my opinion it was a valid question, and listed the various solutions that had worked for others, but not for me. If anyone has insights or ways to improve it, feel free to comment.